# New version of android app

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, updates

I have a native android app in google play and now I have made a new version of the app with ionic 2 framework.
How to update the app and is it possible to notify the users about the new version of the app?
I quess I have to remove the old one and upload the new one.

Comment: if you have added any module for checking update in previous app then you can notify them otherwise not possible

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011

Because you completely rewrote your app please read this too, the most important part is "Prepare your APK":
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

If you follow these guides existing users will be notified about new version automatically by Google Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

The existing users can download the update from your app listing page on the play store or when they select My apps on the Play store. Also if they have enabled auto update for your app then the update will be downloaded and installed automatically.
More about this [here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011)

and as @Abhishek recommended, if you don't have any code for checking updates in your previous version of app then users will not get notified automatically.

also you don't have to remove the old app to upload the new one, you can deactivate the old app if you want it to no longer served to the user, OR you can retain it if you still want it to be served to the users.

Answer (score 0):

Google play usually updates applications automatically. You just need to add upload APK and click Release. You don't have to remove old APK.
In less than a day or something all users of your application will be notified by Google Play that new version is available and if user configures his phone to install apps automatically, then apk will be installed in background as soon as update will be ready.
Also you can notify your users about new version using PUSH notifications. Of course if your previous release does not contain code to enable PUSHes, then you cannot send such notification.
And one more thing: if you use your previous keys to sign APK then everything is fine and you don't need to do anything with APK at developer console, otherwise you need to rollback application and/or re-publish it.